# How to hide inner div component with javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, html

I want to hide div according to some parameter. My aspx contains as follows:

```
<div id="divTecrube" runat="server">
    <section id="tecrube">
        <div class="section-header" id="isTecrubesiDolu" runat="server" >
            İş Tecrübesi                               
        </div>
        <div class="section-header warning"  style="background-color:pink;" id="isTecrubesiBos" runat="server" >
            İş Tecrübesi                                 
        </div>                          
    </section>
</div>
```

my c# code is as follows:

```
Javascript("document.getElementById('isTecrubesiBos').style.display = 'block';");
Javascript("document.getElementById('isTecrubesiDolu').style.display = 'none';");
```

Although I set the right value for property it still shows the both div at the same time. what is wrong I didn't see.

Comment: Why your `id="**isTecrubesiDolu**"` has ** and `id="*isTecrubesiBos*"` has *

Comment: I assume he wanted to highlight them here. Which does not work,

Comment: WHEN does the C# run or gets rendered? Also are they both hidden using CSS?

Comment: the C# runs when the page is loaded

Comment: @HalukÖztürk - can you also paste the function body of the "Javascript" function/method?

Comment: Add attribute ClientIDMode="Static" for each div and your javascript will work.

Comment: whwn ı add ClientIDMode="Static" to divs it worked Thank you @D A